# ORACLE - Return NULL if values from a column are different

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me to create a script for next scenario:

There are credit applications and each credit has sub-products and each sub-product has a score.
Ex. Credit application (`Credit_ID`) 11111 has four sub-products (`Facil_ID`) and for all of them the score is the same 'G' (`Score_Type`)

Credit application 22222 has four sub-products and the score are different for them, some of them has 'G' some of them 'B' some 'Z'.
Put details on the picture.

Request: if `SCORE_TYPE` is the same for all of sub-products then SCORE_TYPE = 'G', if there are different scores at sub-products level, then NULL.

| CREDIT_ID | FACIL_ID | SCORE_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 23 | G |
| 11111 | 25 | G |
| 11111 | 26 | G |
| 11111 | 27 | G |
| 22222 | 67 | G |
| 22222 | 68 | B |
| 22222 | 69 | B |
| 22222 | 70 | Z |

Expected Output:

| CREDIT_ID | SCORE_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | G |
| 22222 | NULL |

My idea was to use

```
CASE 
    WHEN  COUNT(DISTINCT SCORE_TYPE) > 1 THEN null
    ELSE  SCORE_TYPE 
END AS SCORE_TYPE
```

But looks I'm wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your code, but wrap the `ELSE` condition in an aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT credit_id,
       CASE 
       WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT score_type) > 1
       THEN NULL
       ELSE MAX(score_type)
       END AS score_type
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY credit_id
ORDER BY credit_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT Credit_ID,
       CASE WHEN MIN(Score_Type) = MAX(Score_Type) THEN 'G' END AS Score_Type
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Credit_ID;
```

If, for a given credit IT, the smallest and largest score type be identical, then it implies that there is only one score type value.

Comment: Thank you so much, but still doesn't work ((((. The condition for the same values in the column works, but for different doesn't work...Getting the full list of score_type .

Comment: My query works for the sample data you actually posted.  If _your_ data reveals a problem in my answer, then you should include it in your question.

Comment: If I run simple query:

select 
   COUNT(DISTINCT SCORE_TYPE) 
from MYTABLE
where credit_id = '22222'

Get: 1
       1
       1

It calculates number of each value for one application...

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, thank you! But still have questions, appreciate you help! Tim, your code works for me too if score_type is just 'G', but what if score_type get different values, ex. 'M', 'Z', etc.  ?  I've changed your code and put next  CASE WHEN MIN(SCORE_TYPE) = MAX(SCORE_TYPE) THEN SCORE_TYPE ELSE NULL END AS Score_Type . Please correct me where I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it, but It looks like you need to get the 'G' as a SCORE_TYPE result whenever all the SCORE_TYPEs are the same within a certain CREDIT_ID - even when there is no G Score_Type within that Credit_Id. That is how I see this part of the question
(quote) *"Request: if SCORE_TYPE is the same for all of sub-products then SCORE_TYPE = 'G', if there are different scores at sub-products level, then NULL."* (end quote).
In that case the answer below should do the job. It is, actually, the same approach as in the MTO's answer, but in this one the quoted request should be satisfied. I added some more sample data and a listagg selection to make the result more readable, hopefully. Here is the code and the result:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select '11111' "CREDIT_ID", '23' "FACIL_ID", 'G' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '11111' "CREDIT_ID", '25' "FACIL_ID", 'G' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '11111' "CREDIT_ID", '26' "FACIL_ID", 'G' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '11111' "CREDIT_ID", '27' "FACIL_ID", 'G' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            
            Select '22222' "CREDIT_ID", '67' "FACIL_ID", 'G' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '22222' "CREDIT_ID", '68' "FACIL_ID", 'B' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '22222' "CREDIT_ID", '69' "FACIL_ID", 'B' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '22222' "CREDIT_ID", '70' "FACIL_ID", 'Z' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            
            Select '33333' "CREDIT_ID", '85' "FACIL_ID", 'M' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '33333' "CREDIT_ID", '86' "FACIL_ID", 'M' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            
            Select '44444' "CREDIT_ID", '95' "FACIL_ID", 'X' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '44444' "CREDIT_ID", '96' "FACIL_ID", 'Y' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select '44444' "CREDIT_ID", '97' "FACIL_ID", 'Z' "SCORE_TYPE" From Dual 
        )
SELECT 
    CREDIT_ID,
    LISTAGG(SCORE_TYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SCORE_TYPE) "SCORE_TYPES_USED",
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT SCORE_TYPE) > 1 THEN NULL
    ELSE 
        'G'
    END "SCORE_TYPE"
FROM   
    tbl
GROUP BY 
    CREDIT_ID
ORDER BY 
    CREDIT_ID
--
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  CREDIT_ID SCORE_TYPES_USED     SCORE_TYPE
--  --------- -------------------- ----------
--  11111     G, G, G, G           G          
--  22222     B, B, G, Z           Null        
--  33333     M, M                 G          
--  44444     X, Y, Z              Null
```

If I've missunderstood the question and the same Score_Type within a Credit_Id should return the very same Score_Type processed then MTO's answer is exactly what you need. The difference could be seen/tested with the data from my answer having Credit_Id = '33333'. I understood that you need 'G' as a result and MTO understood that it should be 'M' as a resulting Score_Type.
Tim's answer gives exactly the same result as mine. The only difference is that he is using Min and Max aggregations and I am using Count. Anyway the result is the same.
Regards...